# Replacing ASCII value of a char in a string in C

Tags: c, ascii

Is it possible anyhow to increment ASCII value of a char in C? Let's say I have following code

```
int main(){

    char *a = "This is my test string";

    /* *(a+12) += 21; This isnt going */

    printf("%c = %c\n", *(a+12), *(a+12)+21);

    printf("%s\n", a);  

    return 0;
}
```

What I want, for example, is to increment the `e` character with 21 which would be `z` and make it permanent inside that array. So when I use `printf` on the array, it prints `z` on that place instead of `e`.

How would we go about this?

Comment: Yes, exactly like that, but you can't change a string literal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `char *a = "This is my test string";` to `char a[] = "This is my test string";

Comment: Yeah, right declaring it as a pointer made it just read-only -.- But one short question, if it'd be on heap, then I would be able to operate still, right?

Comment: the character array is always on the stack, not the heap here.

Comment: Check this Q which dig in the differences between char * and char[] initialization: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1704407/what-is-the-difference-between-char-s-and-char-s-in-c

Comment: Yeah I know I was just wondering how would it behave with a dynamic array?

Comment: you can change dynamic array the same way. Example, `char *b = malloc( 100 );` `memcpy( b, a, strlen(a) + 1);` `*( b + 12 ) += 21;`

Comment: @Maxitj now that you are no longer a newbie (ie you can vote) consider vote up your accepted answer

Answer (score 0):

Change your

`*a to a[]="This is my test string";`

and by using

`a[12] = a[12] + 21;`

You will find the change in the array;

Comment: Thanks, the other guy was just faster :)